# Select all records from one table that do not exist in another table in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I want to get all the records from a table which do not exist in other table in Laravel 5.1.

I know how to do this in core php, and it works fine with the following code

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

**the model**

```
public function audiences() 
{ 
return $this->belongsTo('App\BridalRequest', 'request_id'); 
}
```

but when i try to do the same in Laravel by using the following code,

```
$all_bridal_requests_check = \DB::table('bridal_requests')
                    ->where(function($query)
                    {
                        $query->where('publisher', '=', 'bq-quotes.sb.com')
                              ->orWhere('publisher', '=', 'bq-wd.com-bsf');
                    })
                    ->whereNotIn('id', function($query) { $query->table('audiences')->select('request_id'); })
                    ->orderBy('created_on', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

then it gives me this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()

Comment: Did you define the relationship in the model class?

Comment: can you provide with the model class code?

Comment: ok here it is... public function audiences()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\BridalRequest', 'request_id');
 }

Comment: try this: public function audiences() { return $this->belongsTo('App\BridalRequest', 'request_id', 'id'); }

Answer (score 16):

The above mentioned query can be built using laravel query builder in the following manner.

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

This is equivalent to below query built using Laravel's query builder.

```
\DB::table('table1 AS t1')
->select('t1.name')
->leftJoin('table2 AS t2','t2.name','=','t1.name')
->whereNull('t2.name')->get();
```

Answer (score 8):

Late but yes I would like to add into this question. Create laravel eloquent relationship between table by writing below code in `users` model file,

```
public function mu_user()
{
  return $this->hasMany(\App\MainUser::class, 'id');
}
```

Now get all records from users table which does not have main user in relation as below,

```
$users = Users::doesnthave('mu_user')->get();
```

If you want to get users who have main_users then you can write query as below,

```
$users = Author::has('mu_user')->get();
```

It's such easy. Hope it helps!

Comment: life saver, i totally didnt see this in the Laravel Docs.  many thanks